# How to indicate that the response body is a List in Swagger UI docs using FastAPI?

Tags: swagger-ui, fastapi, openapi

I describe the structure of the outgoing JSON in the model class, however I cannot make the output as a list.

My model class:

```
class versions_info(BaseModel):
    """ List of versions """
    version : str = Field(..., title="Version",example="2.1.1")
    url :   str = Field(..., title="Url",example="https://ocpi.wedwe.ww/ocpi/2.1.1/")
```

And in the documentation I see:

[image]

However, I need it to be displayed as:

```
[
  {
    "version": "2.1.1",
    "url": "https://www.server.com/ocpi/2.1.1/"
  },
  {
    "version": "2.2",
    "url": "https://www.server.com/ocpi/2.2/"
  }
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since you didn't include your route definition it's hard to say - but usually you do `@app.get('/foo', response_model=List[versions_info])` to indicate that you're returning a list instead of a single object.

Comment: Hi Pavel You are creating ocpi integration for existing central system as well written in Python ?

Comment: Yes,we are the developers of the electric charging stations platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indicate that you're returning a List by wrapping the `response_model` you've defined in `List[<model>]`.

So in your case it'd be:

```py
@app.get('/foo', response_model=List[versions_info])
```